# Why doesn't Dask dashboard update when I run some code?

Tags: python-2.7, dashboard, dask

I'm trying to recreate the behaviour of the Dask dashboard as illustrated in this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1086&v=N_GqzcuGLCY. I can see my dashboard, but it doesn't update when I run a computation.

I'm running everything on my local machine (Kubuntu 18.04).
I used anaconda to set up my environment, including

- python 2.7.14
- dask 0.17.4
- dask-core 0.17.4
- bokeh 1.0.4
- tornado 4.5.1

I set up my scheduler from the command line

```
dask-scheduler
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Clear task state
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:  tcp://192.168.1.204:8786
distributed.scheduler - INFO -       bokeh at:                     :8787
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Local Directory:      /tmp/scheduler-bYQe2p
distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register tcp://127.0.0.1:35007
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://127.0.0.1:35007
```

...and a worker too.

```
 dask-worker localhost:8786
distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:36345'
distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:      tcp://127.0.0.1:44033
distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:      tcp://127.0.0.1:44033
distributed.worker - INFO -              bokeh at:             127.0.0.1:8789
distributed.worker - INFO -              nanny at:            127.0.0.1:36345
distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:       tcp://localhost:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                          4
distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                   16.70 GB
distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/fergal/orbital/repos/projects/safegraph/dask/dask-worker-space/worker-QjJ1ke
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to:       tcp://localhost:8786
distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
```

Then my code, borrowed from the video, is

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

client = Client(processes=False)
print(client)

x = da.random.random((10000, 10000, 10), chunks=(1000,1000,5))
y = da.random.random((10000, 10000, 10), chunks=(1000,1000,5))
z = (da.arcsin(x) + da.arcsin(y)).sum(axis=(1,2))
z.visualize('eg.svg')
z.compute()
```

The code runs, and produces a graph via graph-viz. The bokeh server is accessible at 127.0.0.1:8787/status, and displays a big blue block at the top right, as per the first few seconds of the video. But when I run my code, the webpage doesn't update to show a running computation, nor does it show any results when the computation is finished. Iwould expect to see something like what I see around time 1:20 on the video.

I'm undoubtedly neglecting to set something up properly, but I can't find any clues in either the documentation or on Stack Overflow. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Update dask to 1.1.5, shutdown the dask-scheduler (and dask-worker). I'm guessing my problem was that the version of dask from the default conda channel was out of date. I downloaded the newer version from conda-forge